# Set Power Point custom properties via OOXML

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-js, office-addins

Is it possible to get and set a Power Point document custom properties by manipulating it's OOXML?

I want to do so as Office.js does not have an API to edit PPT custom properties yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API available to access the custom properties from within the add-in. Perhaps your scenario can be accomplished with [settings](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/settings) or [custom XML parts](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/customxmlpart.customxmlpart).

The only way to access the custom properties is to work with the OOXML using an app that is outside of the add-in. If the app is a web app, then it could be surfaced in an add-in; but it could not work on the very same document that the add-in is opened in.

Comment: Are there any sample projects or documentations how to work with OOXML in Office Online (Web) Add-in?

Comment: There are setOOXML and getOOXML methods in Word but they work only with the document content, not metadata like custom properties and there are no such APIs in PowerPoint, so there are no samples or documentation for how to work with OOXML "in" an Office Web Add-in, since you can't (except for the limited Word APIs mentioned above) For information about how to work with OOXML outside of an add-in, start with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa982683(v=office.12).aspx, http://openxmldeveloper.org/, and https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-Sdk

Answer (score 0):

I have checked in power point API documentation of MS add-in. But, I haven't got any solution for get ooxml data.

Also, checked documentation of word and outlook. That document tells us that ooxml content only available in word and outlook. So, we can't get xml format content in power point.

[This image is proof of coercion type of content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXsji.png)

[Fields that are works only in word and outlook.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOTX1.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).